# Drive a relay using V < nominal V

Tags: relay

I’m trying to use this circuit:

[falstad simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%209.78399845368213%201%205%2043%0AI%20176%20208%20240%20208%200%200.5%209%0AI%20240%20208%20304%20208%200%200.5%209%0AI%20304%20208%20368%20208%200%200.5%209%0Ar%20304%20176%20176%20176%200%20100000%0Ar%20240%20208%20240%20272%200%20100000%0Ac%20240%20272%20240%20304%200%201.0000000000000001e-7%208.999999999987732%0Aw%20176%20176%20176%20208%200%0Aw%20240%20272%20176%20272%200%0Aw%20304%20176%20304%20208%200%0Ag%20240%20304%20240%20320%200%0As%20176%20208%20176%20272%200%201%20true%0Ar%20368%20208%20416%20208%200%2010000%0At%20416%20208%20448%20208%200%201%200.5873791893077079%200.6573606294375015%20100%0Ag%20448%20224%20448%20240%200%0A178%20464%2080%20528%2080%200%201%200.2%200.009302102666531501%200.05%201000000%200.013000000000000001%20960%0Aw%20464%20112%20416%20112%200%0Ad%20464%20128%20416%20128%202%201N4148%0Aw%20448%20192%20464%20192%200%0Aw%20464%20192%20464%20128%200%0Aw%20416%20128%20416%20112%200%0Aw%20416%20112%20416%2080%200%0AR%20416%2080%20416%2064%200%200%2040%209%200%200%200.5%0A)
[image]

To drive a relay with the following specs:

- Nominal voltage: 12V DV
- Coil resistance: 960ohm
- Must Operate Voltage: 8.5V DC

  - Nominal Power: 150mW

So I think it requires 12.5mA at 12V to operate.

I don’t have 12V available, so I’m using 9V, and then it would require 16.6mA.

On the breadboard is working, but I guess I need to put a resistor in parallel with the relay coil to lower the coil resistance in order to correctly use 9V. Is that right?
I guess that’s why it is not working on the simulation

Also, is the resistor on the base of the NPN really needed?

Comment: *I don’t have 12V available, so I’m using 9V* I would not use a 12 V relay at 9 V. OK, I would **test it** and I would want it to work reliably at 9 V so I would check if the relay engages already at 7 or 8 V. If it does that: fine. But chances are you will need a relay designed for a lower coil voltage. You could also use a 6 V relay and a series resistor (or diodes) to drop the voltage slightly to 6 V across the relay. Even if the 12 V relay works at 9 V on a breadboard, it might be "on the edge" and stop working when a 9 V battery gets depleted (assuming you're using a battery).

Comment: Putting a resistor in parallel with the relay coil will do no good, it'll only waste power in the resistor. There's nothing you can do beside using a 9V relay or increasing your voltage to 12V.